# heightForRowatIndexPath does not set cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I am trying to create a grouped table view with 3 groups, and each group has cells that are a different height. I've set up 3 prototype cells in my Storyboard with the appropriate heights, and have set up my UITableViewController to return the appropriate heights for each row. However for some reason all of my cells are only 1 pixel tall when they appear on screen.

I've stepped through the code and the correct height and cell is returned for each row. I've also verified that the frame of each cell is correct before it is returned. However calling `rectForRowAtIndexPath` reveals that the `rect` for each row is only 1 pixel tall.

This problem goes away entirely when using a constant cell height. In that situation the cells display perfectly, some of them are just too short/tall since they should be variable height.

Any ideas what is going on here? I'd like to undertand how the rect for each row is determined when using `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Code for heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            return 80.0;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 260.0;
            break;

        case 2:
            return 110.0;
            break;

        case 3:
            return 114.0;
           break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code for `heightForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Post your code without that we will not be abel to help.

Comment: Just added my code. Note I've also tried just returning a single number, which results in the same problem. For example if I set rowHeight to 55 everything works fine, but if I return 55 from heightForRowAtIndexPath all cells are 1 pixel high.

Comment: @cezarcp agreed. I've checked and rowHeight is definitely not set anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to return `NSInteger`.

That should be `CGFloat`.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't believe I missed that. It was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

simply to increase the height for row .simply write the method for height for row at indexpath an simply written

```
if (indexpath.section== 0)

  return 50;
```

Comment: andrew brown you can write therotical part and i m write the coding part .simple difference ..u cant see the difference..:-)))

Comment: This does not work. As stated in my comment above, even just returning 50 (without the if statement) does not work.

Comment: It doesn't work in my project. I need to understand how the height for a cell's rect is determined, and how heightForRowAtIndex path is used to determine that. The correct values are returned from heightForRowAtIndex path, but the cells are not the correct height.

Comment: yaa.this code is working for to increase the row height not cell...i agree with u .